# Stopping a timer when cursor is scrolling richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I'm using a timer1 that stop when the cursor is  inside of a richtextbox, so I tried already few events like Mouse enter, Mouse down and Got focus in order to stop the timer, but those are not working when I am scrolling the richtextbox.
Which event allow me to scroll and keep timer 1 off as cursor is inside of richtextbox?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be no simple, one-event way to do this. As you have discovered, there is no `Enter` or `MouseEnter` event when you click the scrollbar. I think that the following should do the sort of thing you want:

```vb
Private isScrollingRtb As Boolean = False

Private Sub RichTextBox1_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.Enter
    'The RTB received focus.
    Timer1.Stop()
End Sub

Private Sub RichTextBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.Leave
    'The RTB lost focus.
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub RichTextBox1_VScroll(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.VScroll
    If Not ActiveControl Is RichTextBox1 Then
        'The user scrolled the RTB while it did not have focus.
        Timer1.Stop()
        isScrollingRtb = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.MouseEnter
    If isScrollingRtb Then
        'The user left the RTB after scrolling it without focus.
        Timer1.Start()
        isScrollingRtb = False
    End If
End Sub
```

When the user clicks the scrollbar, the `VScroll` event is raised, so you can `Stop` the `Timer` on that event. The problem is deciding when to `Start` it again. In this example, I have chosen to do so when the mouse pointer next goes over the form itself.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately also the event enter is not stopping the timer while scrolling . Obviously i'm doing   Timer1.Stop() under that.

Comment: @Mattia, I have replaced my original answer.

Comment: Hi @jmcilhinney, thanks it works for a richtextbox. Could you assist me also in case of a listbox? I realized there is no Vscroll event in listbox. What evend should I use instead?