# Stopping a timer when cursor is scrolling a Listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I'm using a timer1 that stop when the cursor is inside of a listextbox, so I tried already few events like Mouse enter, Mouse down and Got focus in order to stop the timer, but those are not working when I am scrolling the listbox . Which event allow me to scroll and keep timer 1 off as cursor is inside of listbox? There is a way working for a richtextbox which is using a vscroll event.
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64111534/stopping-a-timer-when-cursor-is-scrolling-richtextbox/64111550#64111550)
Unforutnately listbox haven't any vscroll event.

Thanks

Comment: Standard Controls that use System ScrollBars all generate `WM_VSCROLL` and `WM_HSCROLL` messages. When a ScrollBar is activated, you receive the related message plus `WM_CAPTURECHANGED`. When the `Control.Capture` is `true`, then the ScrollBars is first clicked or it's being dragged, when `Control.Capture` is `false` and you receive a scroll message, then the ScrollBar has been released.

Comment: To avoid doing what you're doing for each and every Control that should *stop the Timer* when interacted with, you can use a class that implements [IMessageFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter) and use [Application.AddMessageFilter()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter) to filter those messages (if this is really required, maybe you could reconsider the whole thing instead, to evaluate if you need this kind of *management*, for whatever you're trying to do).

Comment: Hi Jimi, I'm downloading a textarea text and populating a listbox, so the continuous refresh from the timer is not letting the user to scroll freely the listbox.

Comment: Adding Items to a ListBox doesn't prevent the User from scrolling it. The new Items are not even shown until the User releases the ScrollBar. Unless you're moving the scroll position yourself. Maybe don't do that?

Comment: To me, if I update every 3 seconds a listbox from timer, even Iam  dragging the scrollbar, after timer tick the scrollbar will be release automatically.  Could you please make me a code example usinig WM_VSCROLL and WM_HSCROLL?